# AS3, FlashDevelop: this[ ] not working within return Function

Tags: actionscript-3, return, this, flashdevelop

Well this was interesting -at least for me, in my ignorance. Let the code speak:

```
    public function textSfx(chPos:int, otlPos:int):void
    {
        var sfxTimer:Timer = new Timer (100, 12);
        trace("statSfx fired");
        this["textCh" + chPos + "Stat"].text = this["otl" + otlPos + "Type"] + ": " + this["endOtl" + otlPos + "Stat"];         
        sfxTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, textSfxHandler(chPos, sfxTimer));
        sfxTimer.start();           
    }

    public function textSfxHandler(chPos:int, sfxTimer:Timer):Function
    {
        return function(evt:TimerEvent):void
        {
            trace(this["anything"]);
        }
    }
```

Please be aware that only the textSfxHandler is of pertinence here, the rest is for reference to hopefully better understand it. Notice the use of this[] within the return function: regardless of what you reference via it, it will trace as undefined.

Why such? Is it because this[] cannot be used within the return part, or is it because the return is a function? I've done a workaround (an ugly workaround, involving calling yet another function via the return one where I can make this[] work), but I wondered what the reason was.

Again, the Timer is instantiated within the function as I need a plethora of different ones acting independently from each other rather than one Timer governing it all.

Kinda like the Rings given to the races as opposed to the One Ring -although guess you could argue the One Ring is STILL governing the other rings, but let's stop before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually functions get called in a context, which is refered to by 'this' keyword. An anonymous function (as being returned in the code) has no context and hence your issue.

A cleaner solution for this can be to have another class, say, TimerHandler like:

```
public class TimerHandler
{
    private var _callback:Function;
    private var _chPos:int;
    private var _otlPos:int;

    public function TimerHandler(callback:Function, chPod:int, otlPod:int)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _chPod = chPod;
        _otlPos= otlPos;
    }

    public function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        _callback(_chPos, _otlPos);
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
public function textSfx(chPos:int, otlPos:int):void
{
    var sfxTimer:Timer = new Timer (100, 12);
    trace("statSfx fired");
    this["textCh" + chPos + "Stat"].text = this["otl" + otlPos + "Type"] + ": " + this["endOtl" + otlPos + "Stat"];         

    var sfxTimerHandler:TimerHandler = new TimerHadler(textSfxHandler, chPos, otlPos);
    sfxTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, chPos, sfxTimerHandler.timerHandler);//note I'm not calling timerHandler here... just passing a reference to it.
    sfxTimer.start();           
}

public function textSfxHandler(chPos:int, otlPos:int):void
{
   trace('chPos: ' + chPos + '; otlPos: ' + otlPos);
}
```

Also, the code might not be doing exactly what you want... but it would give you the idea though!

Comment: Ah see i thought twas the function being returned rather than return itself, thanks Catholicon! Lol will have to slowly look through your code with my primitive knowledge though before can implement, but i'm greatly appreciative of the help :)

Comment: It'd be great if you mark the answer correct, if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Lol many apologies, i thought i had! Told ya: ignorance!! Now, to go back through the other peeps who answered my other questions then!